# Blender equivalent of 'graph materials on selected objects'?

Tags: shaders

Former Maya user here. Is there a solid way to 'graph materials on selected objects'? In Maya, you could right-click in the hypershade, select that option and Boom! All the textures and nodes that affect that object show up. Is there an equivalent in Blender? I'm positive it's there, but where?

Reason being, I added an image plane by dragging a png into the scene, and now I want to make it glow and animate and do stuff. But selecting it, I can't see its nodes in the shader editor. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!
-Elliott

Answer (score 0):

Dragging image in scene is equivalent of Add > Image > Reference, creates help Empty object. It's a relatively new feature since 2.80 and there is no native way to convert it to mesh object.

You need to enable addon `Import Images as Planes` and then you will have Image > Images as Planes operator in Add menu, witch create plane with proportions of image and do the shader node setup including transparency.